# loading 64-bit DLLs from memory in C/C++ (Win64)

Tags: c++, dll, win64

pls advise how I can load 64-bit DLLs from memory in C/C++,
i'm running Windows 64-bit mode, I found few solutions for
Win32 but none working correctly with 64-bit

i don't want to create any temporary files, i want to have
all req DLLs into single .bin file and delay-load DLL
into my .exe program

links and example source are most welcome!

thanks

Comment: Is there no way you could simply link these libraries you want to "load from memory" statically to your .exe instead? Loading a DLL from memory is, as far as I know, not really possible. At least not using the Windows API. You could, of course, write your own PE loader, but that would be quite a lot of work…

Comment: unfortunately I've some DLLs no static version available (like fmodex.dll), you're right, I'm prepared for hard work...

Comment: A quick Google reveals https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule

Comment: Here is an additional link (from the same author): https://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/ this one explains the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can load and execute code in memory at runtime, with no temporary files.  Strictly speaking, it's not a DLL, just dynamic code.

You will need the same API functions used by programs that generate code at runtime (many languages these days have just-in-time compilers).

In principle, there are only three steps:

- Get the machine code into dynamically allocated memory.  Whether you read it from a file, transfer it over the network, or generate it using a compiler doesn't matter.
- Mark the pages containing the code as executable.  On Windows, that's done with `VirtualProtect`.  On Linux, `mprotect`.
- Synchronize the instruction and data cache (modern CPUs are a hybrid of Harvard and von Neumann architectures).  On Windows, that's `FlushInstructionCache`.

The latter two bullets will need the base address and size of your buffer containing the code.

What's more difficult is dealing with code that has dependencies.  Since you're not using the OS loader, you have no static import resolution and no fixups.  If your code is designed for this situation (accepts a pointer to the host application data as a function argument and goes through that for all external interactions) this doesn't have to be a problem.  Since you're thinking in terms of a DLL, though, it likely will be.

Still, this is far from an insurmountable problem.  Start by getting a position-independent function working though before you move on to fixups and imports.